Doubt about implementing a high-side switch IC
I'm designing a power switch circuit with the TPS27SA08. This is the application circuit (page 33): 
As you can see, the datasheet says to put protection resistors between the IOs of the IC and microcontroller. I've been trying to guess what are those resistors for, but in the datasheet it only says that those are for IO protection. I want to remove them if they are not necessary.

Note (1) says the device ground will be off relative to the microcontroller ground. The resistors limit the current if the offset causes the gpio protection diodes to conduct.

It's actually explained in some detail in the datasheet. Do you have to meet any standards such as ISO7637-2?

@SpehroPefhany I don't need to meet any of those standards. It's just for a college project. I wouldn't want it to die easily though so a 10k resistor is a good price for that protection

@Kartman That's true. In my case, all electronics grounds are connected to the chasis, so I've just shorted all the grounds of the IC.

Generally speaking having resistors of a few kΩ in series with GPIOs can save  a lot of work in one-off circuits where higher voltages than Vdd are involved. A momentary short or test probe slip is less likely to lead to tedious desoldering and possible spewing of profanities.

The datasheet does mention that they are used for protection during transients such as ISO pulse or reverse supply.
The chip has a lot of optional features. You don't have to implement any of them, if you don't need protection against different failure events, but if you don't implement them your device will damage when such an event happens.
So, do read the reverse supply section in the datasheet and decide if you want to implement that feature or not.
